# Function prints a value but returns none

Tags: python, recursion, return-value, return-type

This function prints the nth fibonacci term.

```
def fib_recur(n, _prev=0, _cur=1, _i=1):
    if n <= 1: print(n)
    elif _i <= n: fib_recur(n, _cur, _cur+_prev, _i+1)
    else: print(_prev)
```

If altered to just return the nth term:

```
def fib_recur(n, _prev=0, _cur=1, _i=1):
    if n <= 1: return n    # <- this return does work
    elif _i <= n: fib_recur(n, _cur, _cur+_prev, _i+1)
    else: return _prev     # <- this return does not
```

The function prints a value but returns None.

Am I missing something or is there something I'm not understanding about the relationship between functions which print vs. return values?

Comment: you are missing a `return` on your `elif`. When the function enters the recursion, the "bottommost" layer returns a value, which is then never returned any further up the chain.

Comment: you said it - "but `returns none`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missing the `return`  in elif condition

```
def fib_recur(n, _prev=0, _cur=1, _i=1):
    if n <= 1: return n    
    elif _i <= n: return fib_recur(n, _cur, _cur+_prev, _i+1) # missing return
    else: return _prev
```